# SSIS- OLE DB source to OLE DB Destination error

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, ssis, oledb

I am pretty new at this. I am trying to transfer 355 rows to the destination

I have 3 columns to transfer `Customer_Number`, `Crime_Type`, `Action_Date`.

When I created the Source table all are `nvarchar(50)`

Destination table is

```
[Customer Number] [float] NULL,
[Crime Type] [nchar](20) NULL,
[Date Closed] [datetime] NULL
```

I have another table doing the same but its running perfectly fine

I don't understand why I get this error

> [OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".
>   [OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[Customer_Number] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
>
> [OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC0209077 occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (15). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

When I connect both source and destination no errors but run time this error happens.

If anyone can help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message already tells you, there is a casting problem:

"Invalid character value for cast specification"

My first guess would be that you have either invalid characters in your Customer_Number or the string exceeds the range of FLOAT.

Comment: Thanks for your help I changed it from the source to nvarchar and now works.

Comment: in my case, full error row was not showing, copy in notepad and see the complete error.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is [Date Closed].  I have yet to successfully get it to convert strings or dates to datetime in an expression.  I have gone so far as to pass in a designated string like '2017-08-08 00:00:00.000' with various iterations for the time and they all have failed several with 'float overflow'.   I have tried even converting the date into a date and then tried to convert the date to a datetime.  I have tried (DT_DATETIME), (DT_DATETIME2) with precision as per several examples on line.  ALL have failed - I have recently read that the OLE DB Destination may be the issue and am looking into the OLE DB Command object and manually writing the insert.
Good luck...